# EXEC-bad-access when invoking block inside a block

Tags: objective-c, ios, objective-c-blocks

### INTERFACE

```
@interface MyClass

@property (nonatomic, copy) SomeBlock someBlock;

@end
```

### IMPLEMENTATION

```
- (void)myMethodWithBlock:(SomeBlock)theBlock
{
  self.someBlock = theBlock;
  [someHelper doSomethingWithCompletionBlock:^(){
        self.someBlock(arg1);
  }
}
```

---

Where `self.someBlock(arg1)` gives me `EXEC_BAD_ACCESS`, I did define `someBlock` to be copied.

What can be the problem?

Comment: Hi, I just checked, it is nil, but why? I even tried with a weak self.

Comment: try with `theBlock(arg1);`

Comment: OK, I found the problem, it is because I set self.someBlock to nil in certain conditions, but the method is called more than once in some other conditions, if the two conditions intersect, then I got the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it looks like the block is sometimes `nil`. When a block is invoked, it's dereferenced, but dereferencing `nil` and `NULL` crashes the app. Check for `if (self.someBlock != nil)` and it should not crash anymore.